# Does Weka Evaluate Sequentially?

Tags: java, weka

I'm working with `UpdatableClassifier` in weka to make sequential training. I'm notice that the `evaluateModel` method of `weka.classifiers.Evaluation` needs to iterate each instance in the `Instances` for the evaluation to take place. I checked the code, it seems weka does the evaluation in a batch way. Is there a way to sequentially evaluate the model using weka classes so that it does not recalculate everything?

Answer (score 1):

Most classifiers need to see all the data before they can be trained, e.g., J48 or SMO. But there are also schemes that can be trained in an incremental fashion, not just in batch mode. All classifiers implementing the weka.classifiers.UpdateableClassifier interface are able to process data in such a way.

Running such a classifier from commandline will load the dataset incrementally (NB: not all data formats can be loaded incrementally; XRFF is one of them, ARFF on the other hand can be read incrementally) and feed the data instance by instance to the classifier.

Check out the Javadoc of the **UpdateableClassifier** interface to see what schemes implement it.

Comment: Yes, but this is how the data is loaded for training not for Evaluating

Comment: i have implemented the same thing. It evaluate as a batch and then store the result in **Fast Vector** for each foid. There is no way as per the documentation that could help in this as far as i know.